# Browserify shim doesn't seem to attach Tether to window object

Tags: javascript, browserify-shim, tether

I have the following in my package.json file:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "tether": "./node_modules/tether/dist/tether.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "$",
  "tether": "Tether"
}
```

And then this in one of my JS modules:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
const Tether = require('tether');
```

I then get the following error in the browser:

> tether.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Tether' of undefined

However, if I don't try to shim Tether and just use `window.Tether` in the module that requires it, it works fine.

```
const $ = require('jquery');
window.Tether = require('tether');
```

Does anyone know why the browserify-shim wouldn't work for Tether in this way?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use the `browser` directive for either of those files because the path is set by the `main` directive in their respective `package.json` files.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could require them direct from node_modules (via their own package files as you say).  The reason I was using the shim for those was because I thought that exposed them to the global `window`.

Comment: The `browser` directive is just for providing an alias to override the file Browserify uses, see https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field, that's part of Browserify core. I think your method of using `window.Tether` is correct if you're looking to have `Tether` available to the rest of your app globally. Another option is to pull Tether via CDN if that's available and use the [`global`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global) setting to pull from the existing `window` rather than re-incorporating the code in your bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - you need to manually specify the `window` object from your bundle.

I'm not 100% sure, but my understanding is that [this part of the documentation](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#multi-shim-example-including-dependencies), when it says

> x exports window.$

actually means that `$` is available to all modules *within the bundle* as `$` - this does not mean the `window` object of your webapp.

See for instance [this issue](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/issues/188).

The problem is in that section of the documentation where it seems people believe the object should be part of the `window` - might be a good idea to change the wording of that.

Comment: I find the docs really don't make it clear what they mean by `window`.  That seems to be the cause of all problems.  I suppose I wanted my requires from within modules to not show that they were attached to the window.  This can probably be done in a config somewhere though.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - just added an [issue](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/issues/210) will look at improving the documentation for that part.